# Does LOCK IN SHARE MODE work with COUNT

Tags: mysql

Does

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parent WHERE NAME = 'Jones' LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

lock the rows in the same way as

```
SELECT * FROM parent WHERE NAME = 'Jones' LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `lock in share mode` specifies:

> `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` sets a shared mode lock on any rows
>   that are read. Other sessions can read the rows, but cannot modify
>   them until your transaction commits. If any of these rows were changed
>   by another transaction that has not yet committed, your query waits
>   until that transaction ends and then uses the latest values.

This would be based on the rows that the transaction reads.  The two queries would generally read the same rows.

*However*, the queries are not equivalent if there is an index on `parent(name)`.  The `count(*)` query can resolve this just using the index, whereas the `select *` would need to read the data pages.  I assume that MySQL would lock the underlying rows during an index-only query, but I am not 100% sure.